# Closing window after clicking 'OK' Button and proceeding to the next window

Tags: jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I don't have any code right now but can anyone give me a link for tutorial or anyone who can give me the idea on how to close a Window after clicking the OK Button and moving to the next window?

I already search tags but it seemed that I didn't find the answer.

Thank you for the future help.

-Christian

Answer (score 0):

Just add an action listener to the button that calls `frame.setVisible(false)` and open a new window (e.g. `newFrame.setVisible(true)`).

```
JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    frame.setVisible(false);
    newFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Mike Laren, it enlighten my confusions. -Christian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way is probably use the "Anonymous inner class" way, as the java designers calls it,
and it goes like this:

```
/// inside the constructor or method where the JButton should be declared 
//and defined:

JButton button1 = new JButton("OK") ;// creating a JButton object
                                 // with the label OK .
// Now Adding an ActionListener to the Button:

   button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // Here starts the anonymous class.. 

   @Override  // This annotation denotes that it overrides
           // an abstract method from the ActionListener abstract class

  public void actionPerformed(actionEvent  e){

        // Now this is where you want to place
        // all command and actions to be performed when the
        // button is clicked

         Name_Of_Frame.setVisible(false);// This makes the frame not visible anymore.
         Name_Of_Frame.dispose() ;     // And this just throws the frame out
                                       // of the stack, and make it available for the
                                       // Garbage Collector.

  } // End of "public void actionPerformed(actionEvent  e){....." method


  }// End of anonymous class.


  ); // End of method call and command " button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

I hope you will manage working out this sample, 
you might also take a look at a nice video tutorial on this subject at:
http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/03/java-video-tutorial-21/

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. sachh_ke_nasdiik.. the codes you provided really help me. -Christian